# Choice between REST API or Java API

Tags: java, api, rest, scalability, neo4j

I have been reading about neo4j last few days. I got very confused about whether I need to use REST API or if can I go with Java APIs.

1. My need is to create millions of nodes which will have some connection among them. I want to add indexes on few of node attributes for searching. Initially I started with embedded mode of GraphDB with Java API but soon reached `OutOfMemory` with indexing on few nodes so I thought it would be better if my neo4j is running as service and I connect to it through REST API then it will do all memory management by itself by swapping in/out data to underlying files. Is my assumption right?
2. Further, I have plans to scale my solution to billion of nodes which I believe wont be possible with single machine's neo4j installation. I also believe Neo4j has  the capability of running in distributed mode. For this reason also I thought continuing with REST API implementation is best idea.
   Though I couldn't find out any good documentation about how to run Neo4j in distributed environment.
3. Can I do stuff like batch insertion, etc. using REST APIs as well, which I do with Java APIs with Graph DB running in embedded mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do you know why you are getting your `OutOfMemory` Exception? This sounds like you are creating all these nodes in the same transaction, which causes it to live in memory. Try committing small chunks at a time, so that `Neo4j` can write it to Disk. You don't have to manage the memory of Neo4j aside from things like cache.
2. Distributed mode is in a Master/Slave architecture, so you'll still have a copy of the entire DB on each system. Neo4j is very efficient for disk storage, a Node taking 9 Bytes, Relationship taking 33 Bytes, properties are variable.
3. There is a Batch REST API, which will group many calls into the same HTTP call, however making REST calls is still a slower then if this were embedded.

There are some disadvantages to using the REST API that you did not mentions, and that's stuff like transactions. If you are going to do atomic operations, where you need to create several nodes, relationships, change properties, and if any step fails not commit any of it, you cannot do this in the REST API.

Comment: RESTfully speaking, you can do complex actions through processing a POST of a document telling the system what to do (POST because it's not idempotent). However, the discoverability of such mechanisms isn't very good unless you do a lot of extra work on descriptive metadata on various things.

Comment: Yes, I'm not bashing `RESTful` web services, but rather the fact the `Neo4j` does not allow transactions across multiple `REST` calls.

Comment: are you sure that when running in cluster, all the instances include the same data? i think i read about a distribution, where the instances just share a portion of data across them, but not all.

Comment: Thanks all!

1. "This sounds like you are creating all these nodes in the same transaction, which causes it to live in memory." I'll check on this. 
But my feeling was that I face OOM when I tried adding nodes to index that were created on various attributes of the node. In my case I have more than 50 attributes over which I want searching, so adding them all to index.

Comment: 2.From your comment it sounds like it keep replicas for load balancing purpose to improve query performance rather than being scalable in terms of storage. But my need was to scale it in terms of storage when I sked about distributed mode.
I appreciate information about node/relationship sizes but still at some point its going to be a limiting factor. Mine is a kind of data warehousing system where we keep adding daily/monthly data while still want to keep old data.
This question remains open & also inherent question that do I need to to use REST APIs only for distributed mode.

Comment: 3. I will check this API but first will look for problem with #1 to see if I need REST API at all.
4. Is there any difference in terms of capabilities if I do use REST API or Java API.

Comment: @user2061385, You OOM is due to RAM issues. Neo4j persists to Disk, unless you are in a transaction. Our system has 100M relationships and some 2 million nodes in our index and we get along just fine with our RAM. For a lengthier discussion, we should take this into a chat.

Comment: @Nicholas - Thanx for sharing this. Then I beleive I must be doing something wrong and as u all suggested Transaction might be culprit. Let me chceck it today.